# Why session is not destroyed, after i destroy it in my logout.php page?

Tags: php, session

I have started session (session_start()) in file which is included in all pages. My link for logout.php is in this file, i ll post code for included file later, also code for my logout.php page.

After i logout, its all ok, but if i click more then 2-3 times on my admin button (which should be active only if $_session['user1'] and $_session['pass'] r correct) i proceed  to admin.php page (after i destroyed session o.O);

Part of my  included file to all pages:

```
<?php
session_start();

    if ((!isset($_SESSION['user1']))&&(!isset($_SESSION['pass1'])))  {
            echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Admin</a></li>";
    } 
    else {
            echo "<li><a href='Admin.php'>Admin</a></li>";
    };

?>
```

logout page:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset ($_SESSION['user1'],$k);
unset ($_SESSION['pass'],$p);
session_destroy();
header('Location:Naslovna.php');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Is `exit()` necessary?

Comment: well, i think that exit() should be after header... so the rest of the code dont execute, but in this case i think its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, solved it with this:

```
unset($user1,$pass);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../index.php');
```

Comment: well its similar what i did before, anyway, when i do like this, first attempt to press admin button leads on login page (like it should cuz session is not set), second attempt lead to login page, too but third time when i press admin button, it leads to admin page, probably because of cash of firefox, or w/e i dont have more ideas, tnx anyway...

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/session_destroy):

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

If you want to truly destroy the session, you have to unset the session cookie yourself.

Comment: tnx for the comment, i saw documentation now, i tried to unset session, u can see my comment at the bottom, i don't have any more ideas, i guess that cookie is still there, u can see my problem still exist.